# Php recrussive dropdown menu help nedded

Tags: php, php-5.3

I need to show a dropdown contain courses i wrote this code to do that. but my problem is it is showing the course categories and subcategories very well. but i need to wrap categories into optiongroup tags. I tired to do that but it failed.

This is  my table structure

```
id  parent_id   course_name
 1       0             UG
 2       0             PG
 3       1             Bsc
 4       3             Computer science
 5       3             Chemisty
 6       2             Msc
 7       6             Computer science
 8       6             Chemistry
```

And here is the php code for recurssion

```
function load_course_category(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('courses_category');
        $this->db->where('parent_id','0');      
        $this->db->order_by("id", "desc"); 
        $query = $this->db->get();

        foreach($query->result() as $row) {     
            $this->db->where('parent_id', $row->id);
            $this->db->from('courses_category');
            $count = $this->db->count_all_results();            
            if($count>0){

                    echo '<optiongroup label="'.$row->course_name.'">';     

            }else{

                    echo '<optiongroup label="'.$row->course_name.'"></optiongroup>';       

            }


            $this->get_children($row->id);
        }

    }

function get_children($parent, $level = 1){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('courses_category');
        $this->db->where('parent_id',$parent);      
        $this->db->order_by("id", "desc"); 
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows()>0){

                foreach($query->result() as $row) {

                    $this->db->where('parent_id', $row->id);                
                    $this->db->from('courses_category');
                    $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
                    if($count>0){   

                        echo '<optiongroup label="'.$row->course_name.'">';         

                    }else{

                        echo '<optiongroup label="'.$row->course_name.'"></optiongroup>';           

                    }
                    $this->get_children($row->id, $level+1);
                }

        }
}
```

Here the optiongroup are not closed correctly. can anyone help me to correct this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening new `optiongroup` no matter of outcome of your `IF` statement, but then you are closing it only `if ($count>0)`